# When I try to use from scipy.io.wavefile import write, it says No module named 'scipy.io.wavefile'

Tags: python

For more details when I try to use
from scipy.io.wavefile import write
it says No module named 'scipy.io.wavefile'
Someone please help my solve this issue

Thanks Aydin,

```
import sounddevice
from scipy.io.wavefile import write


fs=44100
duration=10
print("recording..")
recording_voice=sounddevice.rec(int(duration * fs),samplerate=fs, channels=2)
sounddevice.wait()
write("output.wav",fs,recording_voice)
```

Comment: Did you install scipy; it does not come standard with a Python installation?

Comment: @VirtualScooter yes I did pip install scipy

Comment: OK, good. So what system are you running, what IDE? There many things that can go out of alignment. For example, if you have Anaconda on a Windows system, you should not use `pip install`, but rather `conda install`.

Comment: @VirtualScooter I use visual studio code?

Comment: I have windows so pip install

Comment: I can confirm that the wavefile module is missing from

Comment: the module is scipy.io.wavfile, not scipy.io.wavefile|
(I've made that mistake multiple times! :-)